# Windows CMD -- sort list of files by date modified

Tags: cmd

```
findstr /m foo *.txt
```

lists in alphabetical order the text files containing the string "foo". Is there a way to list the files by modification date?

Comment: Use `dir *.txt /A-D /B /OD | findstr /L /M /F:/ "foo"` or with `/O-D` for newest first and oldest last. Run in the command prompt window `findstr /?` for help on this command which has as full qualified file name `%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe` which should be used in a batch file.

Comment: @Mofi Thanks, that works.